# C ++ files. How to delete a data

Tags: c++, file, io

I need help, I have a program that reads a .txt file and writes it to a new .txt file, which adds data to it at the beginning, that is, if I manage to do it, however, the file it reads comes like this:

```
4.1 data  
4.2 data  
4.3 data
```

what I need is to write but without "4."

for example:

```
1. data  
2. data  
3. data
```

So far I am wearing this, someone can help me.

...

```
        #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        ifstream origen;
        char linea[128];
        char cap[12]="Tema";
        string encabezado= "";
        string nombreArchivo;
        int numEncabezado;

        cout<<"\t\tCARGA ARCHIVO\n"<<endl;
        cout<<"Digite el nombre del archivo o fichero: ";
        getline(cin,nombreArchivo);

        origen.open(nombreArchivo.c_str(),ios::in);
        cout<<"NOMBRE ENCABEZADO"<<endl;
        getline(cin,encabezado);
        cout<<"Numero ?"<<endl;
        cin>>numEncabezado;

        if(origen.fail()){
            cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo";
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            ofstream destino("Copia.txt", ios::out|ios::trunc);
            destino<<encabezado<<endl;
            destino<<cap;
            destino<<" "<<numEncabezado<<endl;
            if(destino.fail())
            cout << "Error al cargar nuevo archivo.txt" << endl;
            else
            {
                while(!origen.eof())
                {
                    origen.getline(linea, sizeof(linea));
                    if(origen.good()) // si lectura ok y
                    if(origen.eof())  // si eof, -> termina
                    exit(1);          // el programa
                    else
                    destino << linea << endl;
                    if(destino.fail())
                    {
                        cerr << "Fallo de escritura en archivo" << endl;
                        exit(1);
                    }
                }

                cout<<"\n\t\tArchivo Cargado Correctamente\n"<<endl;
            }
            destino.close();
        }
        origen.close();

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What does your current output look like?

Comment: like the first example you put up, 
I want to take number "4." away from youn to each line.

Comment: No, I mean what does your output look like right now when you run the code?

Answer (score 1):

You presented plenty of code, but not the text file, so it's hard to tell. But if we assume that the input file always contains stuff like:

```
4.1 data  
4.2 data  
4.3 data
```

Then, you can just replace

```
destino << linea << endl;
```

by

```
destino << linea[2] << "." << linea.substr(3) << endl;
```

But this won't work in general, if your input is

```
1.12 data
145.1 data
```

So, you need to specify, in general, how flexible your input will be. And you'll need code to handle the title.

Comment: ||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
for member 'substr' in 'linea', which is of non-class type 'char [128]'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) 

it gives me an error.